# How to detect specific displayObject has been added to stage using it's class name?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, air

For example i want to add a Label child to every BorderContainer added to stage.
Something like:

```
// called on application preinitialize
private function preInit():void{
    systemManager.stage.addEventListener(Event.ADDED, onElementAdded);
}

protected function onElementAdded(event:Event){  
    trace(event.target);
    if(event.target && event.target is BorderContainer){
        var label:Label = new Label();
        label.text = "This is BorderContainer";
        label.x = 10;
        label.y = 10;
        (event.currentTarget as BorderContainer).addElement(label);
    }

}
```

but all what i get traced is:

```
mouseCatcher
TestApp0
```

I thing it shows only elements which has been added to stage directly.
How can i detect all elements added to application stage? And will this comparison affect application performance, meaning may be some other way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with one. Here instead of listen event from stage use `FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication` instance and we use `ElementExistenceEvent.ELEMENT_ADD` event it provide element as well like event.element so we can do easily.

It also has performance issue but it based on your project. If no longer better you need to remove the listener. Add the listener event when exactly needed else remove the listener.

```
        private function preInit():void{                
            myBC.addEventListener(ElementExistenceEvent.ELEMENT_ADD,onElementAdded);
        }

        protected function onElementAdded(event:ElementExistenceEvent):void
        {   
            //For the as it will return null if it is not of the type you want:
            var bc:BorderContainer = event.element as BorderContainer;

            if(bc){             
                var label:Label = new Label();
                label.text = "This is BorderContainer";
                label.x = 10;
                label.y = 10;
                BorderContainer(event.element).addElement(label);
            }
            else{
             //other than BorderContainer no prototype chain check with is operator.
            }
        }
```

In MXML create custom component name as BorderContainerWithLabel and Add your BorderContainer into BorderContainerWithLabel instead of directly add into Applicationcontainer. So our myBC container actively listen your ADDED  event. so that you can improve performance.

```
<components:BorderContainerWithLabel id="myBC"/>

myBC.addElement(yourBC);
```

BorderContainerWithLabel.mxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:BorderContainer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                   xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                   xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout/>
    </s:layout>
</s:BorderContainer>
```

Comment: I thing ElementExistenceEvent.ELEMENT_ADD not works with elements children, meaning if i add Group with BorderContainer inside, event will fired with Group as event.element but not for it's BorderContainer child.

Answer (score 0):

Why add them after the fact? Create a new class that extends `BorderContainer` instead.

```
public class BorderContainerWithLabel extends BorderContainer {
    public var label:Label;
    public function BorderContainerWithLabel() {
        super();
    }

    override protected function createChildren():void {
        super.createChildren();
        // create the label here. Might have to use addChild() instead of addElement()
    }

    override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void {
        super.updateDisplatList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
        // set positioning and sizing of the label here
    }
}
```

Comment: In my situation application does not know about which component will be extended (added controls or views) and what will be added to it (BorderContainer and Label just an example).

Comment: Best bet is still to create custom classes for each situation, rather than injecting objects into other objects from a parent.